# Group actions on a set

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a finite group acting transitively on the set $A$. Let $p$ be a prime and $S \in Syl_{p}(G)$. Show that $N_{G}(S)$ acts transitively on $Fix_{A}(S)$(the
set of ﬁxed-points of S in A).

I tried to take an element $s$ in $S$, and it fixes $a, a' \in Fix_{A}(S)$. Then there exists a element $g \in G$ such that $ga = a'$. I noted that we also have $s^{-1}gsa = a'$, and want to show that $s^{-1}gs \in N_{G}(S)$, but don't know how to do. Any hint is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You want $g$ to normalize $S$ so you should be looking at $gsg^{-1}$ rather than $s^{-1}gs$. Note that $gsg^{-1}a'=a'$, so $gSg^{-1} \in {\rm Syl}_P({\rm Stab}_G(a'))$ and hence is conjugate to $S$ in ${\rm Stab}_G(a')$.